# Conditional group substitution

Tags: python, regex

```
source= "<br />, systemd-system.conf(5), locale.conf(5),<br />       systemctl(1), journalctl(1), systemd-notify(1), daemon(7),sd-<br />       daemon(3), systemd.unit(5), systemd.special(5), pkg-config(1), kernel-<br />       command-line(7), bootup(7), systemd.directives(7)"
source= sub(compile(r"([\, ]+)(?:([A-Za-z\.\-]+))?(?:(<br /> {7}))?([A-Za-z\.\-]*)(\([0-9]\))", DOTALL), r"\1[\2]\3[\4\5]", source)
```

With this I get unmatched group error.
But on regex101.com this gives

```
<br />, [systemd-system.conf][(5)], [locale.conf][(5)],[]<br />       [systemctl(1)], [journalctl][(1)], [systemd-notify][(1)], [daemon][(7)],[sd-]<br />       [daemon(3)], [systemd.unit][(5)], [systemd.special][(5)], [pkg-config][(1)], [kernel-]<br />       [command-line(7)], [bootup][(7)], [systemd.directives][(7)]
```

The result is not quite the one I expect.
I need

```
<br />, [systemd-system.conf(5)], [locale.conf(5)],<br />       [systemctl(1)], [journalctl(1)], [systemd-notify(1)], [daemon(7)],<br />       [sd-daemon(3)], [systemd.unit(5)], [systemd.special(5)], [pkg-config(1)], <br />       [kernel-command-line(7)], [bootup(7)], [systemd.directives(7)]
```

Test [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kJ6zS2/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you made it to complicated, try this:

```
r"([A-Za-z\.\-]+\([0-9]\))", r"[\1]"
```

It looks for `string-with.extras(5)` and simply surrounds it with `[ ]`

If you want to remove some chars that do not match this regex (like `sd-` in `daemon(7), sd-`), you can use a second one on the result:

```
r"([^[])[A-Za-z\.\-]+", r"\1"
```

which will take any `string-with.extras` that does not have `[` before and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both.
I got there (version 5) but I get unmatched group error in my code.

Solved by adding | just in front br tag (version 7).

Comment: Do you have unmatched groups for both answers, because it is not possible with mine since all groups are mandatory (no `(?:)`)

Comment: I have only one group if <br /> not found. This will be resolved by the 3.5 version of Python. http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/re.html - Changed in version 3.5: Unmatched groups are replaced with an empty string.

Comment: This is a problem with jimmy_keen's regex, what about mine (Math), is it too simple for what you want ?